# Why does my website's session expire before its set time ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config

I have this website which hosted on a server in IIS 7. Its an asp.net website and involves huge trasactions on daily basis. For the last 2 years it worked like a charm but recently it's been exhibiting some problems like not getting logged in, abnormally/abruptly time out before it's set time etc. We rebuild the indexes and it started working fine except for one problem i.e. SESSION TIMEOUT before it's set time i.e. i have set 30 mins in web.config and it sometimes can remain idle for 30 mins, yes it does, ok but most of the time it expires in 10 min, or 5 min or any mins. WHY ? we can't figure out why ?

Help please.

```
<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There can be multiple reasons of this As i understood.**
 If ASP.NET find any of these changes.It will recycle worker process and all state data for applications that are stored in process will be lost which leads to session expiration.
**1)Machine.Config, Web.Config or Global.asax are modified**
**2)The bin directory or its contents is modified**
3)**The number of re-compilations (aspx, ascx or asax) exceeds the limit specified by the  setting in machine.config or web.config  (by default this is set to** 15)

2)There are few settings in IIS that can cause application pool or worker process to be recycled.